# Using variable names for 2d matrix elements for readability

Tags: python, list, matrix

While solving Leetcode problems I've been trying to make my answers as easily intelligible as possible, so I can quickly glance at them later and make sense of them. Toward that end I assigned variable names to indices of interest in a 2D list. When I see "matrix[i][j+1]" and variations thereof repeatedly, I sometimes lose track of what I'm dealing with.

So, for this problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/maximal-square/

I wrote this code:

```
class Solution:
    def maximalSquare(self, matrix: List[List[str]]) -> int:
        
        maximum = 0
        
        for y in range(len(matrix)):
            for x in range(len(matrix[0])):
                
                #convert to integer from string
                matrix[y][x] = int(matrix[y][x])
                
                #use variable for readability
                current = matrix[y][x]
                
                #build largest square counts by checking neighbors above and to left
                #so, skip anything in first row or first column
                if y!=0 and x!=0 and current==1:
                    
                    #assign variables for readability. We're checking adjacent squares 
                    left = matrix[y][x-1]
                    up = matrix[y-1][x]
                    upleft = matrix[y-1][x-1]
                    
                    #have to use matrix directly to set new value
                    matrix[y][x] = current = 1 + min(left, up, upleft)
                    
                #reevaluate maximum
                if current > maximum:
                    maximum = current

        #return maximum squared, since we're looking for largest area of square, not largest side
        return maximum**2
```

I don't think I've seen people do this before and I'm wondering if it's a bad idea, since I'm sort of maintaining two versions of a value.

Apologies if this is a "coding style" question and therefore just a matter of opinion, but I thought there might be a clear answer that I just haven't found yet.

Comment: It's pretty normal to do this for complex expressions that are used multiple times. For something simple like `matrix[x][y]` it's not as common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very hard to give a straightforward answer, because it might vary from person to person. Let me start from your queries:

> When I see "matrix[i][j+1]" and variations thereof repeatedly, I sometimes lose track of what I'm dealing with.

It depends. People who have moderate programming knowledge should not be confused by seeing a 2-D matrix in `matrix[x-pos][y-pos]` shape. Again, if you don't feel comfortable, you can use the way you have shared here. But, you should try to adopt and be familiar with this type of common concepts parallelly.

> I don't think I've seen people do this before and I'm wondering if it's a bad idea, since I'm sort of maintaining two versions of a value.

It is not a bad idea at all. It is "Okay" as long as you are considering to do this for your comfort. But, if you like to share your code with others, then it might not be a very good idea to use something that is too obvious. It might reduce the understandability of your code to others. But, you should not worry with the `maintaining two versions of a value`, as long as the extra memory is constant.

> Apologies if this is a "coding style" question and therefore just a matter of opinion, but I thought there might be a clear answer that I just haven't found yet.

You are absolutely fine by asking this question. As you mentioned, it is really `just a matter of opinion`. You can follow some standard language guideline like [Google Python Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html). It is always recommended to follow some standards for this type of `coding style` things. Always keep in mind, a piece of `good code` is always `self-documented` and putting unnecessary comments sometimes make it boring. Also,

Here I have shared my version of your code. Feel free to comment if you have any question.

```
# Time: O(m*n)
# Space: O(1)

class Solution:
    def maximalSquare(self, matrix: List[List[str]]) -> int:
        """Given an m x n binary matrix filled with 0's and 1's,
        find the largest square containing only 1's and return its area.

        Args:
          matrix: An (m x n) string matrix.

        Returns:
          Area of the largest square containing only 1's.
        """
        maximum = 0
        
        for x in range(len(matrix)):
            for y in range(len(matrix[0])):
                # convert current matrix cell value from string to integer
                matrix[x][y] = int(matrix[x][y])
                
                # build largest square side by checking neighbors from up-row and left-column
                # so, skip the cells from the first-row and first-column
                if x != 0 and y != 0 and matrix[x][y] != 0:
                    # update current matrix cell w.r.t. the left, up and up-left cell values respectively
                    matrix[x][y] = 1 + min(matrix[x][y-1], matrix[x-1][y], matrix[x-1][y-1])
                    
                # re-evaluate maximum square side
                if matrix[x][y] > maximum:
                    maximum = matrix[x][y]

        # returning the area of the largest square
        return maximum**2
```

Comment: Your version is both more readable and concise, thank you for the tips!